# load function always run controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Each time the controller runs I need to load a function init() but this is not working.

```
<script id="misviews.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-view>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-background-positive tabs-color-stable tabs-top tabs-striped" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <ion-tab title="Lista" style="font-weight: bold;">
          <ion-content lazy-scroll>

          </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Mapa" style="font-weight: bold;">
          <ion-content class="map-container">

          </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

This is my ion-view, with two tabs. I need a load a function whenever the driver, this first work, then allowed to run and does not update I need to start.

```
.controller('MisViewsCtrl', function($scope)){
    $scope.init = function(){
      alert("Hi");
    }
    $scope.init();
}
```

I tried this code, too `ng-init="init();"`, and also `data-ng-init="init();"` and none of it worked.

Comment: I mean this as kindly as possible...
What you wrote is very difficult to understand.  It may be difficult for anyone to know what you are asking.

Comment: I'll edit it and write it better.

Comment: You just needed to ask: "How do my reload my controller everytime when a view is activated as Ionic caches views linked to a controller by default."

Comment: Yes, exactly, write and explain me wrong. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not explain well what I needed but fixed. I was checking and the term `ng-init=""` is for data load and no function. I also found that ionic offers certain methods for the views. In those which I found was my mistake and it was not necessary to occupy the policies that I wanted to take. Here is the link and which served me.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){

});
```

[links to ionic view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)